# What type of telescope should I use in order to view the surface of the moon?

Tags: the-moon, telescope

I am wondering what type of telescope I could use to see the surface of the moon. I am fascinated by seeing marks of human feet.

Comment: Please remember that [product recommendations are off-topic on all SE sites](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Answer (score 3):

Depends if you want to do astrophotography or just visual imaging.

Visual imaging then a Newtonian

Astro imaging then a refractor  or bigger scopes for getting those craters really big Cassegrain telescopes  the choice is yours...

Here is just a sample what a refractor and a webcam can do: -

[image: Moon Mosaic]

Comment: Please do full disclosure even if you are not affiliated with mentioned entities.

Comment: Please also avoid mentioning brand names. This practice is not well tolerated on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: unless it's a brand of rocket, in which case it gets a tag and a badge